# Application registry access issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Recently I have created a program that can add executable files to start-up using Visual Studio 2013 that accesses Registry. 
The problem is When click the command which contains the method/action error shows:

> > An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
> >
> > Additional information: Requested registry access is not allowed.

The code inside is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
        Dim keyName As String = txtKeyName.Text
        Dim keyValue As String = txtPath.Text

        regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

        If (regKey.GetValue(keyName)) = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("No value found")
            regKey.SetValue(keyName, keyValue, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
            MsgBox("Key " & keyName & " Has been Created")
        Else
            MsgBox("This Program already exists", vbInformation, "Information")

        End If
```

Comment: Does the SecurityException occur during the read or the write?

Comment: SecurityException occured on this >> regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

Comment: Imho writing to HKLM requires administrator previliges. Have you tried running the application as administrator (Right click, run as administrator)?

Comment: Exactly now it works!

Comment: How can I add to ask permission by default to the application itself?

Answer (score 0):

In order to write to certain parts of the registry, you must have elevated privileges in windows. To force you application to require elevated privileges, you can set this in your project properties >> Application >> View window setting.

Comment: I am using 2012 but I can't imagine 2013 is much different in this respect